# Is there a Grails Polymer Plugin

Tags: grails, polymer

I was wondering if there is a Grails Polymer plugin?  Something which would scaffold the UI using Polymer, and the Grails RESTful controller.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Searching for "Grails Polymer" on Google brought up your question as the number one result, even after just two hours.

Also, searching for "Polymer" on the [Grails plugins site](https://grails.org/plugins/) returned no hits.

So no.